# C# VS2012 place/add code into web pages in the browser

Tags: c#, visual-studio, input, hyperlink, header

I want to know if you can, have a button that links to a web page like this

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

except you can input your own code into the webpage.
much like you can go into the developer tools in chrome and add code.
I want to add code to the header section of the page.

either this or put changes to the values in input fields, so the values are what i want them to be.

thanks for any help

Comment: I'm 99% sure if you run that code on a web server it will try to launch the default browser _on the server_, which I doubt is what you're wanting..

Comment: i know but if you don't put any code in there people just down vote you for not knowing what your on about xD, which is why you come here in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can - use WebBrowser control in your form, navigate to page you like and after navigation is complete add whatever you want to the page.

If you want to do that with just browser and java script on your page - it is not possible due to browser's same origin policy (script on one site can't access properties of pages on other sites).

Comment: i just want to add my js to a webpage, and have it work when the page loads etc, is there a way of doing this with common broswers already like chrome,ie,firefox